# Bearer tokens not working for Twitter's public stream APIs

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I've got a bearer token from `api.twitter.com/oauth2/token`.

However it works only with the REST APIs. Using it against public stream APIs returns me `401 unauthorized`.

I can't find any oauth doc specific to stream APIs.

What am I missing?

**EDIT 1**

Here is the curl command I'm using for my tests:

```
curl --verbose \
  Streaming : -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" \
  --get "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json" \
  --data "follow=150367205"
```

Am I missing some headers? Again, it works fine for the REST APIs.

**EDIT 2**

I've found [an answer](https://twittercommunity.com/t/does-streaming-api-support-application-only-authentication/14670/2) on twittercommunity.com, dating from 2013/06, saying that Twitter's public streaming APIs don't support application-only authentication.

Is it still the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I missed a key point of Twitter's official [documentation on app-only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only):

```
And it won’t be able to:

* ...
* Connect in Streaming endpoints;
* ...
```

Comment: So to harvest twitter data for data analysis, we have to do user authentication?